# Beautifulsoup scraping book catalogue

Tags: screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
for i in range(1,1000000):

    page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.palgrave.com/products/title.aspx?pid="+str(i))
    print "http://www.palgrave.com/products/title.aspx?pid="+str(i)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page) #retreive

    books = soup.findAll("div",{"id":"Title"}) #process
```

I need to crawl through the whole catalogue for a publisher.
I need to retrieve:

- Book Image
- Title
- Edition
- Publisher
- PubDate
- PriceCurrency
- ISBN13
- Description (within an ajax tab)

Comment: I need to pull out the image for every book in the catalogue.

Comment: Could you provide the HTML block that represents an Book?

Comment: http://www.palgrave.com/products/title.aspx?pid=265934 - this is the URL for a book. Within there the id's are: Title, Edition, Publisher, PubDate, PriceCurrency, ISBN13 and Jacket is where the image for the book is located.

Answer (score 0):

use XPath to extract the content from these locations